# Why onReceive in receiver not be invoked?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have declared receivers in Manifest.xml like this:

```
 <receiver android:name=".receivers.MyTrackerReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="998">
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and my custom receiver is

```
public class MyTrackerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String referrerString = extras.getString("referrer");
    Log.v("referrer ", referrerString);

    SharedPreferenceUtils.getInstance(context).setReferrer(referrerString);

    new CampaignTrackingReceiver().onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

}

but the `onReceive` in `CampaignTrackingReceiver`doesn't get called, what I am missing,thanks!

Comment: It's working got the answer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's working now there was some problem with sending broadcast to receiver

Comment: Why it has been down voted as I already mentioned that some error was with my receiver?